# NextJs router push unknown key passed via urlObject

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-router

I have nextjs / react app in which I am using next router to add some queries to my URL. The chrome dev console gives me alot of warnings using this function:

```
  const putTargetsToQueryParams = (targets: IFragranceNote[]) => {
    const data = targets.map(t => encodeURI(t.name)).join(',')
    router.query.fragranceNote = data
    router.push({ ...router, query: data }, undefined, { shallow: true })
  }
```

This works so far but the chrome dev console throws alot of warnings which look similiar to this:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: route
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: asPath
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: components
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: isFallback
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: basePath
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: locale
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: locales
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: defaultLocale
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: isReady
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: isPreview
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: isLocaleDomain
react_devtools_backend.js:2540 Unknown key passed via urlObject into url.format: domainLocales
```

I also tried following approach which leads to the same warnings:

```
  const putTargetsToQueryParams = (targets: IFragranceNote[]) => {
    const data = targets.map(t => encodeURI(t.name)).join(',')
    router.push({ ...router, query: { ...router.query, fragranceNote: data } }, undefined, { shallow: true })
  }
```

The function works, I properly add queries, but I would like to understand why all these warnings occur.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters are incorrect it should look something similar to this:

```
router.push({ 
  pathname: '/', 
  query: { ...router.query, fragranceNote: data } }, 
  undefined, 
  {}
)
```

The pathname is important.

Comment: To make sure you remain on the same page, only updating the query, replace `pathname: '/',` with `pathname: router.pathname,`

Answer (score 0):

What version of next are you using?

Checkout this github issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17339

Comment: I am using 12.0.7, not related to that issue since they say that it has been fixed already